# Swift 3 indexPathForSelectedRow - getting null path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to size a popover view in a segue. The popover works but is in the wrong position.

To set the position, I'm using the following code that tries to select the current IndexPathForSelectedRow, and then set the popover values.

It's not firing, and I am not sure why.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "RecordToNotes" {
           
            if let path = detailsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let cellFrame = detailsTable.rectForRow(at: path)
               
                let vc = segue.destination
                vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
                let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController
                controller?.delegate = self
                controller?.sourceView = detailsTable
                controller?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: cellFrame.midX + 50, y: cellFrame.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
                controller?.permittedArrowDirections = .right
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

The path returns nil.

### Update

I setup the cell in cellAtRow. Here's that snippet:

```
case 2: //notes
                cell.detailPickerButton.isHidden = false
                cell.detailPickerButton.isEnabled = true
                
                cell.detailPickerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detailsViewController.showNotesPanel(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
           ....
```

I am not overriding didSelectRow. Should I?

Comment: I hope you are not calling deselectRowAtIndexPath in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath by mistake. That would make indexPathForSelectedRow nil.

Comment: No, I'm not.  I'm not calling `didSelectRow`. I'm adding the target call in `cellForRow`

Comment: What do you mean your target call is in cellForRow? I hope you intend to show the popover when user selects a particular row and you receive didSelectRowAtIndePath method call.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try translating the frame to your ViewController.View coordinates

use this line

```
controller?.sourceRect = self.view.convert(cellFrame, from: detailsTable)
```

instead of

```
controller?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: cellFrame.midX + 50, y: cellFrame.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Reinier - I'm getting a null path, so I don't get a valid cellRect.

Comment: So that is the issue? @DavidDelMonte, check  if you are deselecting the cell

Comment: Maybe I’m inadvertently deselecting the cell. Im not calling didDeselectCell. Should I?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte if you are getting null path is because you don't have any cell selected obviously, you must have a cell selected or you can use a workaround in case that you don't have any selected

Comment: I should have thought of that. Thanks @Reiner